# HTML5 Drag and Drop Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Thanks for looking at this post

I got a jsFiddle page up to demonstrate my issue [my js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkBgM/)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #div1 {width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
        #div2 {width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
        #div3 {width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
    </style>
    <script>
        function allowDrop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

        function drag(ev)
        {
            ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
        }

        function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
        <p>Drag the image you want into this box!</p>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p><b>Main Image</b></p><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
                <td><p><b>Image 2</b></p><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
                <td><p><b>Image 3</b></p><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <img id="drag1" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/02/thumbnail32.jpg" alt="img01"/></a>
    <img id="drag2" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/html5-css3-wireframing/html5-logo.jpg" alt="img02"/></a>
    <img id="drag3" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)"src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2012/12/thumb-1.jpg" alt="img03"/></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Basically what happen is when I drag the image into the div above ( there 3 div ) , I want to able to **have the image remain where it is and not disappear from its original location**.

The div which the image is drag into should capture the image also, **should new object is drag into the same div** (which previously already drop another image), **the new image should overwrite the old image**.

Another question is If I have a submit button with form post, by taking value of div1,div2,div3, will the browser able capture user input ? e.g drag1 , drag2 or drag3.

**Anyone can help me solve the issue, Thanks for helping !!**

Updated using this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkBgM/3/):

```
function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var new_img = $('#'+data).clone();
$('#'+ev.target.id).html(new_img);
}
```

Using the answer below, the original image retain. but issue is if i drag another picture in a box that already got image, it won't overwrite.

Comment: The solution for your first question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259144/how-to-drag-and-drop-a-copy-of-another-drag-n-dropped-image-using-html5

Comment: long back i made fiddle for myself thought it might help...http://jsbin.com/oluhuk/2/edit

Comment: @João anyone can help me with the updated version

Comment: hi have u solved ur task...

Comment: @codebreaker not really. as u can see the new fiddle, i can put image in but i cant put another image over the existing image on the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your drop function.

```
function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var new_img = $('#'+data).clone();
$('#'+ev.target.id).html(new_img);
}
```

[try this](http://jsfiddle.net/EkBgM/3/)

Comment: Hi there, I tried your code, but If i place another object in the same box, it can't be overwrite with the new image.

Answer (score 0):

```
function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var new_img = $('#'+data).clone();
$('#'+ev.target.id).html("");
$('#'+ev.target.id).html(new_img);
}
```

Try this if it works.