# HTML5 Drag & Drop - Image won't overwrite

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Anyone can help me solve the issue, Thanks for helping !!

Updated using this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EkBgM/3/):

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
var new_img = $('#'+data).clone();
$('#'+ev.target.id).html(new_img);
}

</script>

<body>
<center>
<p>Drag the image you want into this box!</p>

<table>
<tr>
<td><p><b>Main Image</b></p><div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
<td><p><b>Image 2</b></p><div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
<td><p><b>Image 3</b></p><div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>

<img id="drag1" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2013/02/thumbnail32.jpg" alt="img01"/></a>
<img id="drag2" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)" src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/html5-css3-wireframing/html5-logo.jpg" alt="img02"/></a>
<img id="drag3" ondrop="drop(event)" draggable="true" width="150" height="150" ondragstart="drag(event)"src="http://netdna.webdesignerdepot.com/uploads/2012/12/thumb-1.jpg" alt="img03"/></a>
</body>

<style type="text/css">
#div1 {width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
#div2 {width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
#div3 {width:200px;height:200px;padding:10px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
```

Using the code above, the original image retain. but issue is if i drag another picture in a box that already got image, it won't overwrite.

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML5 Drag and Drop Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315002/html5-drag-and-drop-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function allowDrop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
$('#'+ev.target.id).html("");
}
```

Comment: Consider expanding your answer to explain to the asker why this achieves the desired result, possibly linking to documentation. As is, this is only marginally useful.

Comment: yes, I know. But the topic is already duplicated by the same user here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19315002/html5-drag-and-drop-issue?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPFvN/)

Check the fiddle... but the problem arises when you drop over the image. 
You will have to drop over the empty space between the image added and the border. 
As the image added does not have "ondrop" attribute assigned.

```
function drop(ev)
{
 ev.preventDefault();
 document.getElementById(ev.target.id).innerHTML = "";
 var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
 var new_img = $('#'+data).clone();
 $('#'+ev.target.id).html(new_img);
}
```

However, if you clear the innerHTML in allowDrop, it will cause the droppable to be cleared even if the user does not actually drop the image in the area.
Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/NKNZU/)